# Force Android DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString() to ignore the device locale?

Tags: android, date, time, locale, relative-date

I've found using the `android.text.format.DateUtils` relative APIs that return values like "yesterday" or "2 hours ago" very nice - but my app does not support every language Android does.  So, I default to English, but for every language I don't support, the relative string shows in the device's setting.

For example, like:

`Last attempt: hace 11 minutos.`

I'd like to make the API call default to English for any languages I don't support.  However, I don't see anywhere to set the Locale for the API call - I'm hoping I'm just missing it somewhere.

Is there a way to set the Locale just for the API call, ignoring the device setting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the source code of the `DateUtils` class it uses both `Resource.getSystem()` and `Locale.getDefault()` method for formatting date and time. You can change the default `Locale` using `Locale.setDefault()` method but I don't think it's possible to change the return value of the `Resource.getSystem()` method. You can try to change the default locale to `Locale.US` but it seems to me that results will be even worse in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Pixie for looking into it.  I pulled down the source and poked around a bit myself and would have to agree.

Comment: Did anyone find out solution to this problem?

Answer (score 15):

This is working for me up to Android 7

```
  void forceLocale(Locale locale) {
    Configuration conf = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    updateConfiguration(conf, locale);
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    Configuration systemConf = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration();
    updateConfiguration(systemConf, locale);
    Resources.getSystem().updateConfiguration(conf, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    Locale.setDefault(locale);
  }

  void updateConfiguration(Configuration conf, Locale locale) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
      conf.setLocale(locale);
    }else {
      //noinspection deprecation
      conf.locale = locale;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Worked for Android 4.1.2

Comment: Worked for Android 5.0

Comment: Thank you
Worked for Android 7.0

but it doesn't work on Android 8.0 , any idea how to make it work on Oreo